# Recaptcha v3 always returning 0.1 score in mobile

Tags: recaptcha-v3

When trying to log in with an account in my website, I'm always getting 0.1 score in reCaptcha response in mobile.

When I try to log in in desktop, I get between 0.7 and 0.9 all the time, but when I switch to the mobile emulator in Chrome Dev Tools, I'm always getting 0.1. I also tried with my smartphone and the same issue happens.

I tried the code in my local machine and in a dev server and I'm always getting the same error.

The response object I get from the reCaptcha API is the following in mobile.

```py
{
    "success": "1",
    "challenge_ts": "2019-10-07T09:46:46Z",
    "hostname": "<either localhost or my dev server address>",
    "score": "0.1",
    "action": "login"
}
```

If I perform the same action in desktop mode, the score is between 0.7 and 0.9.

I guess I'm doing everything right, as I'm getting the reCaptcha response properly but when I try in mobile mode I always get the 0.1 score.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your api key and create a new one ?

Comment: Also, try to disconnect your chrome browser from your account when you are testing.

Comment: I just did and it works. But, why is this happening? Do I need to change the api key from time to time to avoid this error? Or it is just another kind of issue?

Comment: About your second answer. I've tried with the guest user in Chrome and the problem persists. I mean, with a new API key works, but with the old one and no user it fails.

I'm worried about the fact that the users may get this error in production mode.

Comment: your problem appears in a lot of forums. Many came back in v2. the score is obtained by an obscure google algorithm ... it depends on the number of times your ip uses it (maybe too frequent when you do tests), the browser itself, the time between when the captcha is presented and the time when you answer, what you have in the browser cache, etc ...